# Do I need an activity just to show a notification?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I have an app which only shows a notification (created with [NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification)) and shows Toast and then exits with `finish()` (everything in `onCreate()`). The use case is that when user runs my app, a notification is shown through which certain action can be achieved.

Do I even need an activity for this or is there a faster alternative? It takes some time before it opens and has to load layout although it is not even visible to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
To make an activity as fast as possible without loading layout in it

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Context` to create that Notification. You can use e.g. a `Service`, `Activity`,`IntentService` or `BroadcastReceiver` and more. To create a Toast you also need a `Context`, so where do you currently create the `Toast` and the `Notification`?

Comment: Currently I create them in `onCreate()` of the main activity and get context with `getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

Activity is not mandatory.

**An example**

You can have a `BroadcastReceiver` that shows the Toast Message for example. This way, you can register your `BroadcastReceiver` to listen the event that you want (Like Incoming SMS, Boot Completed etc) and display the toast when the event happens...

In the example below, you will display an Toast after receiving an SMS (regardless the fact that user opened or not your app).

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

    <application>
        ....
        <receiver android:name=".MyCustomBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**MyCustomBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class MyCustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent != null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action != null) {
                if(action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```